# AS3 - How to use Event.EnterFrame?

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I recently asked a question about one of my games, and I think one answer has some potential, but I don't know how to use it. Here is the code:
[Pedestrian Run](http://pastebin.com/0vUajbGr)
The rock seems to just keep going outside the window if I change window size. Any way to fix this and make it go back to the starting block?

Comment: Can you please link us to the game itself?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your only issue but 850 -= 15 in a loop will never == 0. You might try changing the code to.

```
if (rock.x < 0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok as I've answered your previous question, I'll also answer this one since the advice is still semi similar. Although my answer not only provided implementation and fit your current setup, if you are going to use enter frame there are some inherent issues with your `speed` variable considering it decrements for a large amount for an event frame. Note that if these answers are providing relief to your question, please mark it correct so other users may benefit from it.

If you are changing window size keep in mind you continually set:

```
rock.x = 850;
```

in your function `moveRock( e:Event )`, if your window size is obviously smaller than 850 pixels then you are setting the "rock" object outside of that window size once `rock.x = 0`. As @Andrew Sellenrick stated, the moveRock function if statement:

```
if (rock.x == 0)
```

will also potentially cause an issue since you are translating by -15 it is may be that your rock will ever have an x value of 0. Therefore changing your if statement to:

```
if (rock.x <= 0)
```

is the best route to go.

And again, as I also noted in your previous question, you are making an unnecessary removal of the event frame in your `moveRock()`. It should look like this instead:

```
function moveRock(event:Event):void {
    rock.x -= speed;
    if (rock.x <= 0) {
        rock.x = 850;
        rock.y = 520;
    }
}
```

There is no reason to add and remove the event listener there.